# How to sort string in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

How to sort this data in sql server as Pre-OP 1, Pre-Op 2 like wise

```
Pre-OP 1
Pre-OP 10
Pre-OP 11
Pre-OP 12
Pre-OP 13
Pre-OP 14
Pre-OP 15
Pre-OP 16
Pre-OP 17
Pre-OP 18
Pre-OP 19
Pre-OP 2
Pre-OP 20
Pre-OP 21
Pre-OP 22
Pre-OP 23
Pre-OP 24
Pre-OP 25
Pre-OP 26
Pre-OP 27
Pre-OP 28
Pre-OP 29
Pre-OP 3
Pre-OP 30
Pre-OP 4
Pre-OP 5
Pre-OP 6
Pre-OP 7
Pre-OP 8
Pre-OP 9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If data have a space between number and text, you can use the following:

```
order by cast(right(col,CHARINDEX(' ',reverse(col))) as int)
```

Comment: this is a much better solution than all other i feel

Answer (score 1):

I got an answer after doing a little bit of work so would like to share with you all, what are the flaws in this query. Please let me know

```
select room from m_room order by len(room), room
```

Answer (score 1):

`ORDER BY CAST(REPLACE(str, 'Pre-OP ', '') AS INT)`

Comment: that's to a good solution. But is it possible to make it string independent as I will be containing data for Pre-Op, OP, OR etc only changing part will be number rest will remain same

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Order BY 
    CASE WHEN isnumeric(emp_id) = '1' THEN cast (emp_id AS int) 
         WHEN isnumeric(substring(emp_id, 3, 7))=1 THEN cast (substring(emp_id, 3, 7) AS int) 
         ELSE '99999999'
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the sorting on the substring. It will be like `Select * from Table1 order by Cast(SUBSTRING(ColumnName, 7) as INT) ASC`.